# How to convert system.drawing.image to system.web.ui.webcontrols.image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use to store image in bytes and able to convert it to system.drawing.image but not sure how to render it on page

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can create ASPX page that will return image file as byte array with appropriate headers information, to get image you will be able to call this page like `imagemanager.aspx?imgid=31337`

Then in your main page in `system.web.ui.webcontrols.image` control set `ImageUrl` property to your script path:

```
ctrlImage.ImageUrl = "imagemanager.aspx?imgid=31337";
```

Here is example of method to output you image in imagemanager.aspx:

```
    private void TransmitBytes(byte[] bytes, string outFileName)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + outFileName);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`System.Drawing.Image` represents **image** or **picture** that you can render, print, save to file, resize, create thumbnail from etc. But `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` is a **web control** that you can use to show images on web pages.

To show dynamically created image on webpage you need some `handler` or other mechanism that sends image to calling page.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111734/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/042209-1.aspx) is an article on [4guysfromrolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com) that explains this concept.

[Here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5223/using-ashx-files-to-retrieve-db-images/) is another one on [developerfusion.com](http://www.developerfusion.com/) in C#

I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx) very detailed article on MSDN by Scott Mitchel.