# retrieve blob from mysql and display using repeater in asp.net c# and linq datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, linq-to-sql, repeater

I have stored manually images in the field categoryImage in **Longblob** datatype in my category table in **mysql database** . I have added a devart linq-mysql model to retrieve the data from database .

I have added a **linq datasource** to a **repeater** control and want to retrieve blob datatype image from the database directly . when i write this code
 `<%# Eval("CategoryImage" %>`

I get a System.Byte[] as an output . somebody gave me a suggestion that i should convert the byte array to an image using the method

```
    public System.Drawing.Image byteArrayToImage (System.Byte[] ByteInArray)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ByteInArray);
        System.Drawing.Image returnimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnimage;

    }
```

when i wrote this code `<%# byteArrayToImage(Eval("CategoryImage") %>`  It gives me an error that `byteArrayToImage(btye[])` has some invalid arguments. can anyone help me on this problem.

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your tag seems not well formed:

```
<%# byteArrayToImage(Eval("CategoryImage") %>
```

should be:

```
<%# byteArrayToImage(Eval("CategoryImage")) %>
```

Also, the `Eval` method returns `object`, the `byteArrayToImage` method parameter is of type `System.Byte[]`, so you would have to cast it to the proper type.

Additionally, it would be better if you made it clear to what element you are applying the `byteArrayToImage` method returned value. It may not work correctly with the an instance of `System.Drawing.Image`.

If you are trying to create an `<asp:Image>` control based on the `System.Drawing.Image`, it just [won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590055/how-to-add-a-system-drawing-image-to-a-system-web-ui-webcontrols-image) as that control only supports loading an image through an URL.

An alternative to that would be creating a custom HTTP handler for your images or creating a file with the image content and giving the URL to the `<asp:Image>` control.

Comment: should I use http handlers for this as images are stored in database or should i just modify the code behind file to use system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.. what is the better approach for this as i have to retrieve the images from the database itself of long blob datatype

Comment: You will have to use the image control for both solutions. Personally, I would create a HTTP handler that would receive a GET parameter indicating which image to get from the database, load it and return it. And I'd use this handler on the pages I need to show those images.